# REST on GAE, what implementation to use?(RESTlet, jersey, other....)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest

Have somebody experience with using REST on GAE? Maybe you can advise some lightweight REST implementation for this.
I found that RESTlet said that they have GAE optimised implementation. [RESTlet-GAE](http://blog.noelios.com/2009/04/11/restlet-in-the-cloud-with-google-app-engine/)
Anybody try this?

Answer (score 7):

I am currently using GAE plus [Restlet 2.0M6](http://www.restlet.org) for a Goolge Apps Domain specific business project and find it very useful.
Integration with google Accounts and Data Api is easily done for obvious reasons.
However I could not get the XStream lib that is bundled with Restlet to work properly, so I use the very intuitive [Simple framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net) instead for object serialization.
Another disadvantage of Restlet is its lack of JSP integration, which is unfortunate if you do not want to use more heavy-weight templating approaches.
So far I have used XSLTransformations to render browsable html representations, but am not fully satisfied with it yet and always looking for suggestions.

**Update**

I am now using [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) to transform xml on the server. [This is a good tutorial](http://jython.xhaus.com/transforming-with-xslt-on-google-appengine-and-jython/) on how to use it with App Engine. It is in Jython but not too hard to convert.

**Update2**

When the xslt approach is too heavy, I take a different approach with the helper package from the Lift framework to enable enriched [xhtml templating/binding](http://wiki.github.com/dpp/liftweb/how-to-binding-view-content-to-code). This method is based on Scala however.