# Creating a Google App Engine App without a User Interface

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Am trying to create an Android app that uses Google App Engine as a backend, but i want to create the Google App Engine app first then create the Android app to send and get requests from it.The problem is i don't want to go through the pain of writing JSPs to test the app, is there another way of knowing my app works fine without creating a UI (which would be redundant for my final app anyways).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Eclipse to [create an AppEngine project](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating).  Delete the index.html file and its web.xml entry and instead put your RESTful URLs and class names into the web.xml file.  Create a Servlet class for each RESTful URL that you defined and make its doGet method respond with some non-HTML content, for example some JSON, CSV or XML data instead.  Test with your browser or a command line utility such as curl.

After that works, implement request parameters to let the client pass data to the servlet.  Add doPost, doPut and doDelete methods to make the app more RESTful.  Research the addition of libraries such as Jackson and Jersey to do some of the heavy lifting for you (optional).

Comment: Armed with your suggestion, i searched the internet and was able to find a good tutorial that was based on RESTful web services and did exactly what i wanted.Here is the [link](http://www.tutos-android.com/webservice-rest-android-appengine-restlet-objectify) It is however in French and i spent almost an hour translating with Google traduction.I lifted the url from [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1014034/restful-application-on-google-app-engine-java) Stackoverflow question.